# using .replace in gmail to spreadsheet function. Is there anyway to replace everything EXCEPT a selection that matches a pattern?

Tags: google-apps-script

In the body of every email message a certain account will receive, there will be text based urls that ALWAYS follow the same pattern (because they always come from the same place via email filter)
 I want to get this url and copy to the next cell, but his is complicated by the fact that all values update the whole row as an array.
It would be easier to simply .getBody twice to populate the array, the second one with the replace function I am looking for to leave only the URL in the cell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url

Comment: Is your question how to identify a certain pattern? If that's the case, what pattern is that? If the problem is what to do once this pattern is identified, could you share the spreadsheet you are working on, as well as the outcome you expect?